# App ill installed

Tags: internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory

I have attempted to install an app from its apk file, but I failed. It was a game created with RENPY, turns out apps over ~2GB cannot be installed and the app I wanted to install was a bit more. At the time I thought nothing of it, simply something that happens.

Now however I noticed that my device has ~2GB of storage occupied that before were free... only, I cannot "see" them. My assumption is that the apk was installed, Android then checked it, found it couldn't work, sent the error message and then left the installed app. Said app doesn't appear in the list of all apps installed.

How do I remove it and free my storage space?